# IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, kali-linux

I am trying to go live in Kali Linux 2018.3 but whenever I try to do so, it gets stuck at

```
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready 
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready 
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready 
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

although in console,

```
ifconfig
```

detects wlan0 with no issues.
Earlier I used 2016.2 and didn't have the problem Please help.

NIC -

```
Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Your question implies you can't boot, but then you say you have Kali console access. I believe 2018.4 has been released, you could try loading that iso on your USB and try it, or take a look at: https://kali.training/downloads/Kali-Linux-Revealed-1st-edition.pdf, this guide is for beginners to experts. I would suggest taking the time to make your own customized Kali images, it's slightly harder to get going initially, but well worth it. (You can also ensure compatibility for the devices you personally own)

Comment: What I am trying to say is that booting gets stuck and these lines show up. Now when I press ALT+F2, it gives me the console. And yes, I tried the 2018.4. Had no luck

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: I was helping you get enough info in your question to **not** have it closed. And hopefully enough info for someone to be able to adequately answer your question. Read the PDF guy, it's worth it.

Comment: Maybe what this link said is right but being a pentester, I need this OS installed. I have installed it in many other systems and had no problem that couldn't be fixed. This problem occurs only in my laptop. Isn't that funny? This wlan0 error must bypass by itself as it is not that of a problem for OS to load, but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happened but in boot options, when I added

```
nouveau.modeset=0 nvidia.modeset=0
```

it sucessfully booted to Kali Live which means that it wasn't a NIC issue but graphics support issue.

My laptop specs

```
Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ Processor 
Intel® HD Graphics 530
+
Nvidia 960M
```

Answer (score 2):

> ... it gets stuck at:
>
> IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
> IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
> ...

You can shutdown the radio with `nmcli`. [`nmcli`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmcli) is the network manager command line interface.

```
nmcli radio wifi off
```

I use IPv4 wired LAN connection, and I do nothing with Wifi or IPv6. The kicker for me was, an unused radio was killing my LAN connection every half hour. Every half hour I was getting a new IPv4 address, which killed my SSH connection.

We think we tracked it down to RFC 3041, [Privacy Extensions for Stateless Address Autoconfiguration in IPv6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3041). I have no idea why Wireless IPv6 was interfering with my Wired IPv4 addresses. But killing the radio solved the problem.

I miss the old days when things just worked.